# Validate the user name in Unix/Solaris

Tags: c, linux, unix, solaris

Is there any C API for validating user name ?

I am taking input of user_name which might not be present at that point in time.
Since the user name needs to follow POSIX rules, is there any C API which can do the validation?

Comment: See also the following question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949667/what-are-the-real-rules-for-linux-usernames-on-centos-6-and-rhel-6

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are trying to figure out whether a user name exists on the system you are running on. For that, you are looking for `getwpent()`/`getpwnam()` -- check the manual page for details.

Although these return more information than you want, `getpwnam()` will also (easily) tell you if there is or isn't a password file entry corresponding to a given user name.

(If you are simply looking to make sure a user name contains only valid characters, just make sure it only contains `[A-Za-z0-9_]+`)

Comment: The user name should probably not be pure numeric; at the least, you can expect confusion if the user name looks like a number (doubly so if the UID is not the same number as the name — yes, you can do it; no, you should not do it!).

Comment: Yes, that's true. I suppose the right regexp is [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*